# How to open Facebook and Twitter in Application With navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, twitter

I have integrated the facebook but it open in safari, i want it to open in Application having with navigation bar. How can i do this, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I afraid you cant do it so. You have to write your own MVC code to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this framework in order to have navigation bar included modal views for presenting webViews.

```
http://dlinsin.github.com/2011/04/24/DLWebView.html
```